# LINQ/Lambda update List items by spliting them into even groups

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Some background of the application. This is for a WASP and SMPP transmitter accounts I have.

I have a list<> that contains an object that has all the necessary objects for a SMPP PDU and to send a message. 
This list contains a property called "Routing Label" the routing label will indicate which one of the service providers to submit the PDU to (Vodacom, MTN, Cell C).

I have another list of accounts where I can bind to the SMPP server and send messages over. This list also contains the routing label and has a name for the transmitter account. So for example Vodacom's routing label is "D082" and I have two accounts that I can bind to simultaneously.

I now need to take the first List<> and update the fields. Lets say the first List<> has 1000 items. I will need to split these(more or less evenly) amongst all the accounts I have for each "Routing Label" that occurs in the second List<> mentioned.

I would prefer to achieve the desired functionality using linq or lambda.

**Edited**:Added code example so that you kind people may help me :-) Sorry for the poor standard but I *quickly* stripped some code out for you guys. I hope this helps with my problem.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        List<MobileAccounts> TransmitterAccounts = new List<MobileAccounts>();//This list contains my transmitter accounts


        MobileAccounts item = new MobileAccounts();
        item.FriendlyName = "Vodacom 1";
        item.RoutingLabel = "D082";
        TransmitterAccounts.Add(item);

        MobileAccounts item1 = new MobileAccounts();
        item1.FriendlyName = "Vodacom 2";
        item1.RoutingLabel = "D082";
        TransmitterAccounts.Add(item1);


        MobileAccounts item2 = new MobileAccounts();
        item2.FriendlyName = "MTN 1";
        item2.RoutingLabel = "D083";
        TransmitterAccounts.Add(item2);


        MobileAccounts item3 = new MobileAccounts();
        item3.FriendlyName = "MTN 2";
        item3.RoutingLabel = "D083";
        TransmitterAccounts.Add(item3);

        MobileAccounts item4 = new MobileAccounts();
        item4.FriendlyName = "MTN 3";
        item4.RoutingLabel = "D083";
        TransmitterAccounts.Add(item4);

        MobileAccounts item5 = new MobileAccounts();
        item5.FriendlyName = "CellC 1";
        item5.RoutingLabel = "D084";
        TransmitterAccounts.Add(item5);

        MobileAccounts item6 = new MobileAccounts();
        item6.FriendlyName = "CellC 2";
        item6.RoutingLabel = "D084";
        TransmitterAccounts.Add(item6);


        List<SubmitSm> col = new List<SubmitSm>();//this list contains messages in a queue ready for sending

        SubmitSm sitem = new SubmitSm();
        sitem.DestAddr = "0722222222";//Vodacom number
        sitem.RoutingLabel = "D082";
        col.Add(sitem);

        SubmitSm sitem1 = new SubmitSm();
        sitem1.DestAddr = "0722222220";//Vodacom number
        sitem1.RoutingLabel = "D082";
        col.Add(sitem1);

        SubmitSm sitem2 = new SubmitSm();
        sitem2.DestAddr = "0722221212";//Vodacom number
        sitem2.RoutingLabel = "D082";
        col.Add(sitem2);

        SubmitSm sitem3 = new SubmitSm();
        sitem3.DestAddr = "0830000000";//MTN number
        sitem3.RoutingLabel = "D083";
        col.Add(sitem3);


        SubmitSm sitem4 = new SubmitSm();
        sitem4.DestAddr = "0833746005";//MTN number
        sitem4.RoutingLabel = "D083";
        col.Add(sitem4);

        SubmitSm sitem5 = new SubmitSm();
        sitem5.DestAddr = "0749999998";//CellC number
        sitem5.RoutingLabel = "D084";
        col.Add(sitem5);

        /*
         * Now this is where I will need
         * to split all the messages in "col"
         * amongst all the transmitter accounts
         * I have. 
         */


    }

public class MobileAccounts
{
    /*Please note not all items 
    are in this class. I have
    * removed some as they are not
    * neccessary for this demo code.               
    */

    //[DataMember]
    public string FriendlyName;

    //[DataMember]
    public string BindName;

    //[DataMember]
    public string BindPassword;

    //[DataMember]
    public string BindHost;

    //[DataMember]
    public string BindPort;

    //[DataMember]
    public string BindType;

    //[DataMember]
    public string ProviderCode;

    //[DataMember]
    public string RoutingLabel;


}

public class SubmitSm
{
   /*Please note not all items 
    are in this class. I have
    * removed some as they are not
    * neccessary for this demo code.               
    */
    public byte DefaultMessageId { get; set; }

    public string DestAddr { get; set; }

    public byte DestAddrNpi { get; set; }

    public byte DestAddrTon { get; set; }

    public string MessageText { get; set; }        

    public byte PriorityFlag { get; set; }

    public byte ProtocolId { get; set; }

    public byte RegisteredDelivery { get; set; }                

    public string ScheduleDeliveryTime { get; set; }

    public string ServiceType { get; set; }

    public string SourceAddr { get; set; }

    public byte SourceAddrNpi { get; set; }

    public byte SourceAddrTon { get; set; }

    public string ValidityPeriod { get; set; }

    public string RoutingLabel { get; set; }

}
```

Thank you to all who have contributed. @NinjaNye your solution is close but does not exactly fit my requirements. I do appreciate your effort though.

I *think* I am almost there but I am struggling.  Can someone, anyone please help me figure out the sub select shown below:

```
List<IGrouping<string, MobileAccounts>> sad1 = TransmitterAccounts.GroupBy(y => y.RoutingLabel).ToList();
col = (List<SubmitSm>)col.Select
                                (x =>
                                    {
                                         x.ServiceType = sad1.Where
                                                               (z =>
                                                                   z.Key==     x.ServiceType
                                                                        )                                                    
                                                                        .Select
                                                                            (y =>
                                                                                    new
                                                                                    {
                                                                                        //this should return the Transmitter account that has the lowest count

                                                                                        TransmitterAccount = y.OrderBy(ui => x.ServiceType.Count()).Select(ui => ui.FriendlyName).First()
                                                                                    }
                                                                            ).First().TransmitterAccount;                                                  

                                              return x;
                                      }
                                    ).ToList();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Although I'm sure it's possible to understand your question with some background, it's hard without seeing the relevant code. It looks like you've got two custom types here - for the items to be transmitted, and for the routing information. Showing the relevant properties of these classes would help. It would also help to see the code that you wrote to try tackling this problem yourself - it is often easier to fix someone else's code than to write new code from scratch.

Comment: The question is simple, I have a bunch of fruit that goes to different shops. And I have a bunch of shops with several baskets each. I want to split the fruit designated for each shop evenly between their baskets. The answer however is not so easy... Working on it but maybe someone smarter than me will get there first :p

Comment: @DaveWilliams: ha ha ha!!! Your comment put a smile on my face this morning. But yes Dave you are 100% correct. I hope the code posted above will be of assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only use of Linq I can see here would be the use of `.Skip()` and `.Take()` however I have created an extension method to tidy things up a bit.  This will mean you can simply write the following to split any `IEnumerable`.

```
// In your example above you need to replace `items` with your `col` variable
var result = items.Split(transmitter.Count());
```

The extension method

<s>http://www.ninjanye.co.uk/2013/07/splitting-distributing-list-objects.html</s>

http://jnye.co/Posts/10/evenly-splitting-distributing-a-list-of-objects-using-linq-and-extension-methods

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Split<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int groups)
    {
        var listedSource = source.ToList();
        int extra;
        int groupSize = Math.DivRem(listedSource.Count(), groups, out extra);

        while (listedSource.Any())
        {
            int newSize = groupSize;
            if (extra > 0)
            {
                newSize++;
                extra--;
            }
            yield return listedSource.Take(newSize);
            listedSource = listedSource.Skip(newSize).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

**The result**

I set this up as a quick command program to test

Here are some results so you can see how items are split:
[image: Example output of splitting]

**Initial post (now refactored above)**

<s>Something like this should do it... however I have simplified the example</s>

```
        // This is your transmitter count
        int groups = 4; 
        // These are your SMS's
        List<int> values = new List<int>(){1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

        //Calculate group size
        int extra;
        int groupSize = Math.DivRem(values.Count, groups, out extra);

        var result = new List<IEnumerable<int>>();
        while (values.Any())
        {
            int newSize = groupSize;
            if (extra > 0)
            {
                // Account for extras
                newSize++;
                extra--;
            }
            result.Add(values.Take(newSize));
            values = values.Skip(newSize).ToList();
        }

        return result;
```

Answer (score -1):

you shoud avoid LINQ with side effects. But you can attach the object in the lists like that.

```
        List<MobileAccounts> mas = new List<MobileAccounts>();
        List<SubmitSm> sms = new List<SubmitSm>();

        var result = mas.Select(ma => new {Sm=(sms.First(sm => sm.RoutingLabel == ma.RoutingLabel)),Ma=ma});
        foreach (var r in result)
        {
            //update Properties here
        }
```