# Distributing jobs fairly on accounts - distribution algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm

I'm working on a project that publish to a multiple websites using a multiple accounts. each account can publish to a specific website. as shown in the 'Dict' below. The problem is I'm trying to distribute the publishing jobs on accounts fairly and making a distance between accounts that has more than 1 job.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public struct Job
    {
        public string Site { get; set; }
        public string Account { get; set; }
    }


    private  static readonly Dictionary<string, List<string>> Dict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
    private  static List<string> _accounts;


    public static void Main()
    {
        var sites = new List<string>{"Site-A", "Site-B", "Site-C", "Site-D", "Site-E"};
         _accounts = new List<string>{"Account-A", "Account-B", "Account-C", "Account-D", "Account-E"};

        // Permissions dictionary. specify accounts that has a permessions to  publish on a particular Site
        Dict.Add("Site-A", new List<string>{"Account-A", "Account-C"});
        Dict.Add("Site-B", new List<string>{"Account-A", "Account-E"});
        Dict.Add("Site-C", new List<string>{"Account-C", "Account-D"});
        Dict.Add("Site-D", new List<string>{"Account-A"});
        Dict.Add("Site-E", new List<string>{"Account-A"});

            var jobs = new List<Job>();
            foreach (var site in sites)
            {
                var job = new Job();

                // Get an account that has a permissions to publish on 'site'
                // checking against the permissions dictionary Dict
                var account = GetAccountCanPost(Dict, site, _accounts);

                job.Site = site;
                job.Account = account;

                jobs.Add(job);
            }


            var jobsCountForEachAccountDict = CalculateJobsCountForEachAccounts(jobs);

            //////#### Now.. We need to re Order Jobs and swipe it here before send it to processing ####.....//////

            foreach (var job in jobs)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(job.Account + " publish on " + job.Site);
            }

    }

     public static Dictionary<string, int> CalculateJobsCountForEachAccounts(List<Job> jobs)
        {
            var dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();

            foreach (var job in jobs)
            {
                if (dict.ContainsKey(job.Account))
                    dict[job.Account]++;
                else
                    dict.Add(job.Account, 1);
            }

            return dict;
        }


     public static string GetAccountCanPost(Dictionary<string, List<string>> dict, string targetSite, List<string> accounts)
        {
            var accountIdsAssoc = GetAccountsIdsAssociatedWithCommunity(dict, targetSite);

            var selectedId = PickRandom(accountIdsAssoc, new Random());
            var account = accounts.FirstOrDefault(s => s == selectedId);

            return account;
        }

     private static List<string> GetAccountsIdsAssociatedWithCommunity(Dictionary<string, List<string>> communitiesAccountsAssociationsDict, string communityId)
        {
            if (communitiesAccountsAssociationsDict.ContainsKey(communityId))
                return communitiesAccountsAssociationsDict[communityId];

            return null;
        }

         private static T PickRandom<T>(IList<T> list, Random random)
        {
            var index = random.Next(0, list.Count);
            return list[(int) index];
        }

}
```

when the jobs are created it is something similar to this: (Before re-adjusting the jobs distribution)

```
> Account-A Publish on Site-A 
> Account-E Publish on Site-B
> Account-D Publish on Site-C
> Account-A Publish on Site-D
> Account-A Publish on Site-E
```

The publishing jobs created above are not fairly distributed to accounts, as you can see 'Account-A' has 3 jobs assigned while there's an other accounts can publish to the 'sites' as defined in 'Dict' so it should look something like:

```
> Account-C Publish on Site-A
> Account-E Publish on Site-B
> Account-A Publish on Site-D
> Account-D Publish on Site-C
> Account-A Publish on Site-E
```

In the output above the jobs are distributed fairly on accounts and also there's a distance between accounts that has more than 1 job

An example on distance between jobs:

```
    > Account-A Publish on Site-A 
    > Account-E Publish on Site-B
    > Account-D Publish on Site-C
    > Account-A Publish on Site-D
    > Account-A Publish on Site-E
```

Job 4 and 5 are being processed by Account-A. An account should not process two jobs sequentially, so it could be swapped with another job.

It will be highly appreciated if you could help. I need an algorithm that do the job distribution to get similar output. Performance is not important.

Thank you..

Comment: Its not distributing evenly because its an uneven distribution of sites to accounts. If you want your accounts even, then just select a random account **then** chose a random site.. In that case the easiest approach would be to flatten your accounts which has a list of sites (not vice versa)

Comment: Hi can you elaborate on "max distance between accounts" part?

Comment: @Suparshva I have updated the question, please have a look

Comment: @AronF - I'd like an idiots guide to job distribution. Can you explain it to me like I'm 5?

Comment: @Enigmativity Please have a look to the question again. Added more details. 
The publishing jobs above are not fairly distributed to accounts, as you can see 'Account-A' has 3 jobs assigned while there's an other accounts can publish to the 'sites' as defined in 'Dict' so we need to distribute the publishing jobs on accounts making sure that jobs are distributed to accounts fairly when possible. thanks a lot

Comment: You can take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17616173/linq-lambda-update-list-items-by-spliting-them-into-even-groups. This might help you.

Comment: Please check my solution at https://dotnetfiddle.net/g9OaJm

Comment: ...is this a spam/troll/astroturf bot?

Comment: @Flater No, it's not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be improved, but this will do what you need:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public struct Job
    {
        public string Site { get; set; }
        public string Account { get; set; }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Dictionary<string, List<string>> permissionsDict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
            permissionsDict.Add("Site-A", new List<string> { "Account-A", "Account-C" });
            permissionsDict.Add("Site-B", new List<string> { "Account-A", "Account-E" });
            permissionsDict.Add("Site-C", new List<string> { "Account-C", "Account-D" });
            permissionsDict.Add("Site-D", new List<string> { "Account-A" });
            permissionsDict.Add("Site-E", new List<string> { "Account-A" });

            // get responsibilities rate for each account

            Dictionary<string, int> responsibilitiesRate = GetResponsibilitiesRate(permissionsDict);

            List<Job> jobs = new List<Job>();

            // building jobs list

            foreach (var permission in permissionsDict)
            {
                var job = new Job();
                job.Site = permission.Key;

                // for the current site, see what account has lower responsibility rate
                int minResponsibilities = permission.Value.Min(x => responsibilitiesRate[x]);
                string account = permission.Value.First(x => responsibilitiesRate[x] == minResponsibilities);
                responsibilitiesRate[account]++;

                job.Account = account;
                jobs.Add(job);
            }

            // order jobs making sure distance between accounts has more than 1 job

            jobs = RandomOrderResponsibilities(jobs);

            foreach (var job in jobs)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(job.Account + " publish on " + job.Site);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static Dictionary<string, int> GetResponsibilitiesRate(Dictionary<string, List<string>> dict)
        {
            Dictionary<string, int> responsibilitiesCount = new Dictionary<string, int>();

            foreach (var kvp in dict)
            {
                foreach (var account in kvp.Value)
                {
                    if (responsibilitiesCount.ContainsKey(account))
                    {
                        responsibilitiesCount[account]++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        responsibilitiesCount.Add(account, 1);
                    }
                }
            }

            return responsibilitiesCount.OrderBy(x => x.Value).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
        }

        private static List<Job> RandomOrderResponsibilities(List<Job> jobs)
        {
            bool couldComplete = true;
            var maxIterations = 1000;
            var iterationCount = 0;

            do
            {
                // shuffle
                jobs = jobs.OrderBy(a => Guid.NewGuid()).ToList();

                for (int i = 1; i < jobs.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (jobs[i].Account == jobs[i - 1].Account)
                    {
                        couldComplete = false;

                        for (int j = i + 1; j < jobs.Count; j++)
                        {
                            if (jobs[j].Account != jobs[i].Account)
                            {
                                // swipe
                                var temp = jobs[i];
                                jobs[i] = jobs[j];
                                jobs[j] = temp;
                                couldComplete = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                iterationCount++;
            } while (!couldComplete && iterationCount < maxIterations);

            return jobs;
        }
    }
}
```

Output (random solution):

```
Account-A publish on Site-D
Account-C publish on Site-A
Account-A publish on Site-E
Account-D publish on Site-C
Account-E publish on Site-B
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, You solution is close to what  I try to accomplish. It's very close to my solution code. Your solution has an issue, that  if 'Dict' is changed, then the solution will give invalid results, it assigns a job to an account that is not allow to publish as in 'Dict' . the 'Dict' are dynamically created. Could you please re-adjust the solution to it can adapt new changes to 'Dict'.?

Comment: Are you sure? Unless you solution, mine's doesn't picks randomly. I can't see a case when it'd fail.

Comment: Your solution just works fine, Thanks a lot. you're master. It will be highly appreciated if you could extend the solution to make it select random accounts each time. +1

Comment: Kindly note that 'responsibilitiesCount' is only the permissions dict. it states what account has a permission to publish on each site. Instead of 'foreach (var kvp in Dict)' we need to  loop the 'sites'

Comment: I've updated the answer with random solution picks. I use `responsibilitiesCount` to know on with sites every account has rights as it helps make the distribution fair.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Kindly note that 'responsibilitiesCount' is only the permissions dict. it states what account has a permission to publish on each site. Instead of 'foreach (var kvp in Dict)' we need to loop the 'sites' Please have a look on my solution.. dotnetfiddle.net/g9OaJm .. I really appreciate your help

Comment: `responsibilitiesCount` in my solution states for count of how many sites each user can publish on

Comment: Aaah, you solution solves another problem, but I think your solution can be adjusted to loop the sites list instead of the responsibilitiesCount and assign a job to each account. Thank you for your help

Comment: I'm sorry my problem explanation is bad. I think now you have an idea of what I'm trying to accomplish.. thank you for your time

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what's missing as every output is giving the first post solution within a random order.

Comment: Thanks for response. please have a look on execution result at https://dotnetfiddle.net/7sYrax you will see that Account-B has no distance between jobs. can we adjust the order method to at least make some distance?

Comment: I see the issue. I'll fix it in few hours or tomorrow morning with a better logic.

Comment: Thank you. You are the master. I appreciate it